# Use appsrc to do streaming through gstreamer udpsink

Tags: c, video-streaming, gstreamer

My source code is mainly from http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-data-spoof.html which works well when play locally through xvimagesink.

> This example application will generate black/white (it switches every second) video to an Xv-window output by using appsrc as a source with caps to force a format. We use a colorspace conversion element to make sure that we feed the right format to your X server. We configure a video stream with a variable framerate (0/1) and we set the timestamps on the outgoing buffers in such a way that we play 2 frames per second.

Pipeline likes this when play locally:

```c
gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), appsrc, conv, videosink, NULL);
gst_element_link_many (appsrc, conv, videosink, NULL);
```

Then i tried to use udpsink replace the videosink like this:

```c
gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), appsrc, conv, videoenc, payloader, udpsink, NULL);
gst_element_link_many (appsrc, conv, videoenc, payloader, udpsink, NULL);
```

It doesn't work. with debug-level 3 it gives me warning below:

```
0:00:00.033631637 10534      0x1f4d4a0 FIXME                default gstutils.c:3643:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<source:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
0:00:00.034634957 10534      0x1f4d4a0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2933:gst_base_src_loop:<source> error: Internal data flow error.
0:00:00.034664369 10534      0x1f4d4a0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2933:gst_base_src_loop:<source> error: streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
```

Full source code attached.

```c
#include <gst/gst.h>

static GMainLoop *loop;

static void
cb_need_data (GstElement *appsrc,
        guint       unused_size,
        gpointer    user_data)
{
    static gboolean white = FALSE;
    static GstClockTime timestamp = 0;
    GstBuffer *buffer;
    guint size;
    GstFlowReturn ret;

    size = 385 * 288 * 2;

    buffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate (NULL, size, NULL);

    /* this makes the image black/white */
    gst_buffer_memset (buffer, 0, white ? 0xff : 0x0, size);

    white = !white;

    GST_BUFFER_PTS (buffer) = timestamp;
    GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale_int (1, GST_SECOND, 2);

    timestamp += GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer);

    g_signal_emit_by_name (appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);

    if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK) {
        /* something wrong, stop pushing */
        g_main_loop_quit (loop);
    }
}

gint
main (gint   argc,
        gchar *argv[])
{
    GstElement *pipeline, *appsrc, *conv, *videosink, *payloader, *udpsink, *videoenc;

    /* init GStreamer */
    gst_init (&argc, &argv);
    loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

    /* setup pipeline */
    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline");
    appsrc = gst_element_factory_make ("appsrc", "source");
    conv = gst_element_factory_make ("videoconvert", "conv");
    videoenc = gst_element_factory_make("ffenc_mpeg4", "ffenc_mpeg4");
    videosink = gst_element_factory_make ("xvimagesink", "videosink");
    payloader = gst_element_factory_make("rtpmp4vpay", "rtpmp4vpay");
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(payloader),
            "config-interval", 0,
            NULL);
    udpsink = gst_element_factory_make("udpsink", "udpsink");
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(udpsink),
            "host", "127.0.0.1",
            "port", 5000,
            NULL);

    /* setup */
    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (appsrc), "caps",
            gst_caps_new_simple ("video/x-raw",
                "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGB16",
                "width", G_TYPE_INT, 384,
                "height", G_TYPE_INT, 288,
                "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 0, 1,
                NULL), NULL);

#if 0
    // THIS WORKS!
    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), appsrc, conv, videosink, NULL);
    gst_element_link_many (appsrc, conv, videosink, NULL);
#else
    // THIS DOESN'T WORK
    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), appsrc, conv, videoenc, payloader, udpsink, NULL);
    gst_element_link_many (appsrc, conv, videoenc, payloader, udpsink, NULL);
#endif

    /* setup appsrc */
    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (appsrc),
            "stream-type", 0,
            "is-live", TRUE,
            "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME, NULL);
    g_signal_connect (appsrc, "need-data", G_CALLBACK (cb_need_data), NULL);

    /* play */
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    g_main_loop_run (loop);

    /* clean up */
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));
    g_main_loop_unref (loop);

    return 0;
}
```

Can be compiled with:

```
gcc app1.c -o app1 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-base-1.0` `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0` -g -lgstapp-1.0
```

.sdp file for testing:

```
v=0
m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
a=rtpmap:96 MP4V-ES/90000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i worked this out with gstreamer1.0.

I guess the problem is the colorspace. After switching to gst1.0 and change the videoenc to avenc_mpeg4, it works. With gst0.10 i think add a ffmpegcolorspace before videoenc could do the same trick.

Working code can be found on https://gist.github.com/beeender/d539734794606a38d4e3

Compile with:

```
gcc app1.c -o app1 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-base-1.0` `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0` -g -lgstapp-1.0
```

Test with:

```
vlc test.sdp
```

See sdp file in my question.